# ORACLE GOLDEN GATE COLSEXCEPT not working

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I am trying to replicate a tables from production into the data warehouse.  There are columns that I don't want the transactions for when an update is performed only on those columns.  I was under the impression that the COLSEXCEPT command is what I needed to use

```
(
https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/gg_parameters160.htm#GWURF546

{COLS | COLSEXCEPT} (column_list) Selects or excludes columns for processing.
TABLE
)
```

In my table the BL_ARREARS_IND column needs to be excluded since it is not in my target table.  When I update only the BL_ARREARS_IND column in the source it is still logging the transaction in turn sending it to the target server.

I have an extract and a pump set up.

```
EXTRACT extbill

SETENV (ORACLE_SID=******)
SETENV (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1)
USERID *****, PASSWORD *****
EXTTRAIL /u01/dwdev/oggdev/product/12.1.2/oggcore_2/dirdat/lb
TRANLOGOPTIONS ASMUSER SYS@ASM8, ASMPASSWORD ******

TABLE tmp.bill, &
KEYCOLS(ACCT_ID, BILL_SEQ_NO), &
**COLSEXCEPT(BL_ARREARS_IND);**

DISCARDFILE ./dwdev_ggdev_bill.dsc, APPEND
DiscardRollover at 02:00 ON SUNDAY
```

---

```
EXTRACT pumpbill

RMTHOST tst.corp.intranet, MGRPORT 7812
RMTTRAIL /u01/dwtst/oggdev/product/12.1.2/oggcore_2/dirdat/rb
TABLE tmp.bill **COLSEXCEPT(BL_ARREARS_IND);**
```

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the COLSEXCEPT command.  I thought a transaction would only be created if a change was made to a field that was not in the COLSEXCEPT list.  It still creates a transaction, but just doesn't send those fields to the target database (still not sure why you would create a transaction to changes to fields you are excluding).

I'm sure there is a better way, but I was able to get it to work using what I call a workaround by applying a filter to the table in the extract. This was a cumbersome process because the table has 82 fields.  Had to compare the BEFORE image to the AFTER image for all of the other 81 fields that I do need.

When you have this many arguments in a FILTER you have to increase the FUNCTIONSTACKSIZE to accomodate (which in my case required a DBA to make the change).

I know there has to be a better way to handle this, but here is the code that worked for me:

---

TABLE tmp.bill, KEYCOLS(ACCT_ID, BILL_SEQ_NO), COLSEXCEPT(BL_ARREARS_IND),
FILTER(ON UPDATE,((@BEFORE(ACCT_ID) <> @AFTER(ACCT_ID)) or (@BEFORE(BILL_SEQ_NO) <> @AFTER(BILL_SEQ_NO)) or (@BEFORE(ACTUAL_BALANCE_AMT) <> @AFTER(ACTUAL_BALANCE_AMT)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(AFTER_CYCLE_CHG_IND),@AFTER(AFTER_CYCLE_CHG_IND)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(AGGREGATION_ID) <> @AFTER(AGGREGATION_ID)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(APPLICATION_ID),@AFTER(APPLICATION_ID)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BANK_ACCOUNT_NO),@AFTER(BANK_ACCOUNT_NO)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BANK_CODE),@AFTER(BANK_CODE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BAN_STATUS),@AFTER(BAN_STATUS)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BAN_STATUS_DATE),@AFTER(BAN_STATUS_DATE)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(BF_ADJ) <> @AFTER(BF_ADJ)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BF_BTN),@AFTER(BF_BTN)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(BF_CALL_CHG) <> @AFTER(BF_CALL_CHG)) or (@BEFORE(BF_IMM_ADJ) <> @AFTER(BF_IMM_ADJ)) or (@BEFORE(BF_MON_SRV_CHG) <> @AFTER(BF_MON_SRV_CHG)) or (@BEFORE(BF_ONE_TIME_CRG) <> @AFTER(BF_ONE_TIME_CRG)) or (@BEFORE(BF_TAXS) <> @AFTER(BF_TAXS)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BILLING_METHOD),@AFTER(BILLING_METHOD)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BILL_CONF_STATUS),@AFTER(BILL_CONF_STATUS)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BILL_DATE),@AFTER(BILL_DATE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BILL_DUE_DATE),@AFTER(BILL_DUE_DATE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BILL_STATUS_DATE),@AFTER(BILL_STATUS_DATE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(BL_BAL_HANDLE_IND),@AFTER(BL_BAL_HANDLE_IND)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(CARRY_OVER_IND),@AFTER(CARRY_OVER_IND)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(CH_BAL_CHGS) <> @AFTER(CH_BAL_CHGS)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(CREDIT_CARD_NO),@AFTER(CREDIT_CARD_NO)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(CREDIT_CARD_TYPE),@AFTER(CREDIT_CARD_TYPE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(CR_CARD_AUTH_CODE),@AFTER(CR_CARD_AUTH_CODE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(CR_CARD_EXP_DATE),@AFTER(CR_CARD_EXP_DATE)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(CURR_CHARGE_AMT) <> @AFTER(CURR_CHARGE_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(CURR_CREDIT_AMT) <> @AFTER(CURR_CREDIT_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(CURR_OC_CHRG_AMT) <> @AFTER(CURR_OC_CHRG_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(CURR_RC_CHRG_AMT) <> @AFTER(CURR_RC_CHRG_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(CURR_UC_CHRG_AMT) <> @AFTER(CURR_UC_CHRG_AMT)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(CYCLE_CLOSE_DATE),@AFTER(CYCLE_CLOSE_DATE)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(CYCLE_CODE) <> @AFTER(CYCLE_CODE)) or (@BEFORE(CYCLE_RUN_MONTH) <> @AFTER(CYCLE_RUN_MONTH)) or (@BEFORE(CYCLE_RUN_YEAR) <> @AFTER(CYCLE_RUN_YEAR)) or (@BEFORE(DEPOSIT_PAID_AMT) <> @AFTER(DEPOSIT_PAID_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(DEPOSIT_REQ_AMT) <> @AFTER(DEPOSIT_REQ_AMT)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(DL_SERVICE_CODE),@AFTER(DL_SERVICE_CODE)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(DL_UPDATE_STAMP) <> @AFTER(DL_UPDATE_STAMP)) or (@BEFORE(FGN_COUNTY_TAX_AMT) <> @AFTER(FGN_COUNTY_TAX_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(FGN_FED_TAX_AMT) <> @AFTER(FGN_FED_TAX_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(FGN_LOCAL_TAX_AMT) <> @AFTER(FGN_LOCAL_TAX_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(FGN_STATE_TAX_AMT) <> @AFTER(FGN_STATE_TAX_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(FREE_MINUTE_STATUS) <> @AFTER(FREE_MINUTE_STATUS)) or (@BEFORE(LATE_PYM_BASE_AMT) <> @AFTER(LATE_PYM_BASE_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(MASTER_BAN) <> @AFTER(MASTER_BAN)) or (@BEFORE(MB_BILL_SEQ_NO) <> @AFTER(MB_BILL_SEQ_NO)) or (@BEFORE(NM_ADR_LINK_SEQ_NO) <> @AFTER(NM_ADR_LINK_SEQ_NO)) or (@BEFORE(NON_TELECOM_AMT) <> @AFTER(NON_TELECOM_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(NUM_OF_PRODUCTS) <> @AFTER(NUM_OF_PRODUCTS)) or (@BEFORE(OPERATOR_ID) <> @AFTER(OPERATOR_ID)) or (@BEFORE(PAST_DUE_AMT) <> @AFTER(PAST_DUE_AMT)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(PAYMENT_METHOD),@AFTER(PAYMENT_METHOD)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(PAY_ARR_AMT_DUE) <> @AFTER(PAY_ARR_AMT_DUE)) or (@BEFORE(PAY_ARR_AMT_REM) <> @AFTER(PAY_ARR_AMT_REM)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(PRD_CVRG_END_DATE),@AFTER(PRD_CVRG_END_DATE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(PRD_CVRG_STRT_DATE),@AFTER(PRD_CVRG_STRT_DATE)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(PREV_BALANCE_AMT) <> @AFTER(PREV_BALANCE_AMT)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(PRODUCTION_DATE),@AFTER(PRODUCTION_DATE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(PRODUCTION_REQUEST),@AFTER(PRODUCTION_REQUEST)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(PRODUCTION_TYPE),@AFTER(PRODUCTION_TYPE)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(PRODUCTS_NUM_CALLS) <> @AFTER(PRODUCTS_NUM_CALLS)) or (@BEFORE(PRODUCTS_NUM_MINS) <> @AFTER(PRODUCTS_NUM_MINS)) or (@BEFORE(PYM_RECEIVED_AMT) <> @AFTER(PYM_RECEIVED_AMT)) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(SYS_CREATION_DATE),@AFTER(SYS_CREATION_DATE)) = 0) or (@STREQ(@BEFORE(SYS_UPDATE_DATE),@AFTER(SYS_UPDATE_DATE)) = 0) or (@BEFORE(TAX_FED_AMT) <> @AFTER(TAX_FED_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(TAX_FED_USF_AMT) <> @AFTER(TAX_FED_USF_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(TAX_LOC_AMT) <> @AFTER(TAX_LOC_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(TAX_ROAM_AIR) <> @AFTER(TAX_ROAM_AIR)) or (@BEFORE(TAX_ROAM_SRV_CHARGE) <> @AFTER(TAX_ROAM_SRV_CHARGE)) or (@BEFORE(TAX_ROAM_TOLL) <> @AFTER(TAX_ROAM_TOLL)) or (@BEFORE(TAX_STT_AMT) <> @AFTER(TAX_STT_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(TELECOM_AMT) <> @AFTER(TELECOM_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(TOTAL_BILLED_ADJUST) <> @AFTER(TOTAL_BILLED_ADJUST)) or (@BEFORE(TOTAL_BILLED_CHARGE) <> @AFTER(TOTAL_BILLED_CHARGE)) or (@BEFORE(TOTAL_COUNTY_TAX) <> @AFTER(TOTAL_COUNTY_TAX)) or (@BEFORE(TOTAL_DUE_AMT) <> @AFTER(TOTAL_DUE_AMT)) or (@BEFORE(TOTAL_TAX_FEES) <> @AFTER(TOTAL_TAX_FEES))));

Answer (score 0):

That code wasn't able to compare nulls. I came up with this macro which gave me the right output.

```
Filename: check_col.mac

Contents:

MACRO #check_col
PARAMS (#ICOL)
BEGIN
(
(0 = @IF (@COLTEST (@BEFORE(#ICOL), NULL, MISSING),0,1) AND 1 = @IF (@COLTEST (#ICOL, NULL, MISSING), 0, 1))
OR
(1 = @IF (@COLTEST(@BEFORE(#ICOL), NULL, MISSING), 0, 1) AND 0 = @IF (@COLTEST (#ICOL, NULL, MISSING), 0, 1))
OR
(0 = @STREQ(@BEFORE(#ICOL),#ICOL))
)
END;
```

You can use this macro in the INC file for the mapping like the below:

```
INCLUDE dirprm/check_col.mac

TABLE S1.T1, KEYCOLS(COL1, COL2), COLSEXCEPT(COL123), FILTER(ON UPDATE,(#check_col(COL3) or #check_col(COL4));
```

***If you map more than 5 columns in this fashion, the code will throw a STACK SIZE NOT ENOUGH error, FUNCTIONSTACKSIZE = 5000 solves it. Let me know what negative effects this param has got.***